# Como hacer que git ignore ficheros (configurar .gitignore)

Tags: windows, git

Estoy aprendiendo a usar git haciendo un proyecto sencillo en Java sin utilizar un entorno de desarrollo (compilando directamente desde la terminal). Quiero que git me ignore los ficheros `.class` que como ya sabréis son los binarios de Java.

He estado investigando como hacer esto y lo tengo que hacer es crear un fichero `.gitignore` con una línea que contenga la siguiente regla: `*.class`.

El problema que tengo es que no se donde poner ese fichero, supongo que en el directorio raíz de mi proyecto o en el directorio `.git`. ¿Alguno ha hecho esto alguna vez y me puede ayudar?

PD: Estoy utilizando Windows utilizando el programa que me he descargado de la [página oficial](https://git-scm.com/).

Comment: Lo tienes que poner en el raíz de tu proyecto.

Comment: Tú mismo te has respondido. Lo pones en la raiz de tu proyecto

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no hay ningún problema por resolver.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que esta haciendote copia de esos ficheros? En principio debería de gestionar sólo los que tengas indexados.

Comment: En https://www.gitignore.io puedes buscar tu tipo de proyecto y te devuelve el .gitignore que te viene mejor y a partir de ahí añades o eliminas lo que quieras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tenía es que no vale solo con crear el fichero (en el directorio que sea) `.gitignore`. Luego hay que añadirlo al proyecto con `git add` y luego hacer `commit`.

Comment: Esto no es cierto

Comment: ¿En qué me he equivocado? @kerunaru

Comment: En que no hace falta hacer commit del `.gitignore` para que funcione.

Comment: ¿Con el ```add```` vale? Lo cambio. Gracias por la info @kerunaru

Comment: A ver… El `.gitignore` hay que versionarlo, sí. Pero desde el primer momento en el que lo creas ya se tiene en cuenta incluso sin hacerle `add` o `commit`.

Comment: @kerunaru es que hasta que no lo _versione_ no le hacia caso. Puede ser tema de windows a lo mejor en linux es diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es ponerlo en la raíz de tu proyecto y ingresar lo siguiente:

Si tienes una carpeta llamada "folder"
escribe: /folder/ y con eso ignorara todo el folder completo.
Si es un archivo "ejm.class" escribe: /path/ejm.class

Comment: No entiendo bien lo de la carpeta. ¿Dónde exactamente tengo que escribir eso?

Comment: ¡Gracias! Me has ayudado a encontrar la solución al problema.